# Sorting with Tuple in Python with non-Latin strings as keys

Tags: python

I have figured out how to sort list which return a tuple with false.
This key works when language is in English but won't work when translated to Japanese.

```
key=lambda x:(x.name!='Iraq', x.name)
```

This one won't work.

```
key=lambda x:(x.name!='イラク', x.name)
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 5):

Add at the top of the file the following lines in order to support utf8:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Post a demo so we can repro the issue, otherwise it'll be difficult to help you.